# add users to team foundation server 2008 using TFS SDK

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

How do I add users to the contributors group of one of my TFS 2008 projects using TFS SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I think does what you need (untested):

```
# add me to the Contributors security group on MyTeamProject
$tfs = Get-TfsServer njtfs -all
$user = $tfs.gss.ReadIdentityFromSource($tfs.GSS_SearchFactor::AccountName, "rberg")
$uri = $tfs.css.GetProjectFromName("MyTeamProject").uri
$role = $tfs.gss.ListApplicationGroups($uri) | ? { $_.displayname -match "Contributors" }
$tfs.gss.AddMemberToApplicationGroup($role.Sid, $user.Sid)
```

Translating to C# or other .Net languages should be simple.